# Some styles are not being applied with webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I'm learning to bundle modules together with webpack and have run into a problem. In my src folder I've made a CSS file (style.css), a JS file (home.js) that holds a function and one more JS file (index.js) that I import them both into before appending to my page.

I've added a background image to the body in style.css which loads just fine, however the styling I've applied to one element (the 'hi' div) does not seem to be applied. The elements class does show up when inspecting the element on the page.

Why does this not work - what am I not seeing?

All three files are pasted here:

```
//index.js:

console.log('hello world');
import square from './home.js';
import './style.css';
const content = document.getElementById('content');

content.appendChild(square());

//home.js:

export default function square() {
    const hi = document.createElement('div');
    hi.classList.add('black');
    hi.textContent = 'boo';

    return hi
};

//style.css:

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100wv;
    background-image: url('food.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
};

.black {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because your component loads before than your style.css.

Comment: Thank you - I figured it might have something to do with that. Any pointers on how I may fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the below article hope this resolve the issue

```
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = `
          .note {
            color:"#000";
          }
        `;

document.head.appendChild(style);
```

the below link have few examples

https://www.javascripttutorial.netenter code here/dom/css/add-styles-to-an-element/#:~:text=First%2C%20select%20the%20element%20by,properties%20of%20the%20style%20object.

Answer (score 0):

// I would prefer you to use this also you can provide dynamic css on the go

```
var temp = document.getElementById("temp");

const dynamicValue = 10; 
const darkMode = true;

const styles = `
    background-color:${darkMode ? '#000' : '#fff'};
    color:${darkMode ? '#fff' : '#000'};
    width:${innerWidth - 100}px;
    height:${innerHeight - 100}px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:${dynamicValue}px;
`

temp.setAttribute("style", styles)
```